# Enum with identical cases names with associated values of different types

Tags: swift, enums

The following Swift code compiles:

```
enum GraphDataSource  {
    case array(data: [Double], start: Double?, step: Double?)
    case pairs(XYValues: [Double: Double])
    case pairs(dateValues: [Date: Double])
    case function((Double) -> Double?)

    func localizedName() -> String {
        // TODO: Create localizable strings
        return NSLocalizedString(Mirror(reflecting: self).children.first?.label ?? "", comment: "")
    }
}
```

It has two enum cases named `pairs`. 
But when I try to extract associated value, it turns out that I can't choose the one I want.

```
    var graphData = GraphDataSource.function(sin)

    switch graphData {
    case .pairs(dateValues: let vals):
        vals.keys.forEach({print($0)})
    case .pairs(XYValues: let xy): // without this case everyting compiles OK
        xy.keys.forEach({print($0)})
    default:
        break
    }
```

The error is: "Tuple pattern element label 'XYValues' must be 'dateValues'".
Is this normal? Feels like compiler should either disallow cases of the same name or allow to switch on both.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is a Swift compiler bug. See [SR-10077](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-10077).

Comment: What a relief to know that!

Comment: Can you clarify your answer about which part is the bug? Is it the mistaken ability to have two enums with the same name but different associated values or is it the inability to code the `switch` statement for the two cases?

Comment: According to the bug, it is supposed to be legal; the compiler just can't actually do it.  I'm not aware of anything in the Swift docs that says whether this should be legal or not.

Comment: For people coming by, this issue is still open at the day of comment. Feel free to register on the swift board to watch and up vote this bug. o/

Answer (score 2):

There are two workaround to pass different types of associated values throw the one `case`:

1. Use `Any` type for an associated value and then dynamically type check/cast it:

```swift
enum DataType {
    case data(_ value: Any)
}

func process(_ type: DataType) {
    switch type {
    case .data(let value):
        if value is Int {
            print("Int value - \(value)")
        }
        else if value is String {
            print("String value - \(value)")
        }
    }
}

process(.data(10)) // Outputs: Int value - 10
process(.data("Text")) // Outputs: String value - Text
```

2. Use an additional `enum` to specify a needed type:

```swift
enum ValueType {
    case int(_ value: Int)
    case string(_ value: String)
}

enum DataType {
    case data(_ value: ValueType)
}

func process(_ type: DataType) {
    switch type {
    case .data(let value):
        switch value {
        case .int(let value):
            print("Int value - \(value)")
        case .string(let value):
            print("String value - \(value)")
        }
    }
}

process(.data(.int(10))) // Outputs: Int value - 10
process(.data(.string("Text"))) // Outputs: String value - Text
```